# PHP sort 2d array alphabetically by nested value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting

I have a PHP array that looks like this:

```
Array{
    [0] {
        'id'       => '0',
        'title'    => 'foo',
        'address'  => '123 Somewhere',
    }
    [1] {
        'id'       => '1',
        'title'    => 'bar',
        'address'  => '123 Nowhere',
    }
    [2] {
        'id'       => '2',
        'title'    => 'barfoo',
        'address'  => '123 Elsewhere',
    }
    [3] {
        'id'       => '3',
        'title'    => 'foobar',
        'address'  => '123 Whereabouts',
    }
}
```

and I want to sort it by the 'title' key in the nested arrays, to look like this:

```
Array{
    [1] {
        'id'       => '1',
        'title'    => 'bar',
        'address'  => '123 Nowhere',
    }
    [2] {
        'id'       => '2',
        'title'    => 'barfoo',
        'address'  => '123 Elsewhere',
    }
    [0] {
        'id'       => '0',
        'title'    => 'foo',
        'address'  => '123 Somewhere',
    }
    [3] {
        'id'       => '3',
        'title'    => 'foobar',
        'address'  => '123 Whereabouts',
    }
}
```

The first level key values don't matter since I'm keeping track of each nested array via the nested key 'id'.

I've played with ksort() but with no success.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP sort multidimensional array by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-value)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should use usort() (i'm assuming PHP 5.3+ here):

```
usort($your_array, function ($elem1, $elem2) {
     return strcmp($elem1['title'], $elem2['title']);
});
```

Edit: 
I hadn't noticed you wanted to preserve index association, so you actually need to use `uasort()` instead, with the same parameters.

Edit2:
Here is the pre-PHP 5.3 version:

```
function compareElems($elem1, $elem2) {
    return strcmp($elem1['title'], $elem2['title']);
}

uasort($your_array, "compareElems");
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed. There are a few alternative solutions on SO but this seems more elegant than most (or all) of them.

Comment: Hmm have just transferred to a server with PHP <5.3, so the embedded function doesn't work.. how would I refactor this to achieve the same effect with the function() outside uasort?